# Dummit Foote Exercise 1.7.10.a permutations of subsets self-study

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions

**Problem Statement:**

Let $A$ be a nonempty set and let $k$ be a positive integer with $k\leq\left|A\right|$. The symmetric group $S_A$ acts on the set $B$ consisting of all subsets of $A$ of cardinality $k$ by $\sigma\cdot\{a_1,...,a_n\}=\{\sigma(a_1),...\sigma(a_n)\}$.

For which values of $k$ is the action of $S_n$ (the symmetric group) on $k$-element subsets faithful?

**My Answer:**

Case 1: $k=\left|A\right|=1$

The only permutation group in $S_1$ is $1$ therefore k is faithful on $B$.

Case 2: $k=\left|A\right|\neq1$ and finite

The cardinality of $B$ is 1. It is the set of all elements of $A$. Therefore all permutations mapping $B$ to $B$ are the same and $S$ is not faithful.

Case 3: $k<\left|A\right|\neq1$ and finite

For any $b\in B$ a transposition of any two $a\in b$ is a permutation such that $\sigma b=b$. Therefore $S$ is not faithful.

**Discussion:**

I've googled up three solution manuals that say that $S$ is faithful in case 3. Each provides a different proof, none of which I can fully track. I think I must be misunderstanding a definition somewhere.

Here is an example that I think illustrates S not being faithful in case 3:

$A=\{1,2,3,4\}$

$b=\{1,2\}$

$\sigma=(1 2)$

$\sigma b=\{2,1\}=\{1,2\}=b$

Where am I wrong? This is self-study, so any additional coaching on my thinking would be appreciated.

Comment: You are just wrong. For instance, let’s take $|A|=3$ and $k=2$. You are acting on the set $B$ that consists of $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, and $\{2,3\}$. An element of $S_3$ acts on $B$; for example, the element $(1,2,3)$ acts on $B$ by sending $\{1,2\}$ to $\{2,3\}$, $\{1,3\}$ to $\{2,1\}$, and $\{2,3\}$ to $\{1,3\}$. Note the action is faithful, because if $\sigma$ sends $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,3\}$ to itself, then it fixes $1$, and hence must fix $2$ and $3$. What you did has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Got it. I definitely misunderstood the definition of faithful.

Answer (score 1):

What I missed was that if S is not faithful then $\sigma_2^{-1}\sigma_1b=\sigma b=b$ and $\sigma_1\neq\sigma_2\iff\sigma\neq 1$ must hold for all $b\in B$ for some $\sigma\in S$. I thought I could get away with only showing it for a single element $b$ because I did not understand the definition of faithful.

In case 3 for any $\sigma\neq1$ we can choose a $b$ that doesn't contain the second element of the first cycle of $\sigma$ but does contain the first element. This means that $\sigma b\neq b,$ which is a contradiction. We can choose no $\sigma$ meeting the requirements for all $b$. As a result S must be faithful.